# .htaccess serving subfolder at from url of another subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My folder structure looks like this:

```
    /.htaccess
    /admin
    /admin/api
    /admin/admin
    index.html (Angular JS app)
```

So I need to do the following rewrites:

1. Serve `/admin/admin` at `/admin`
2. Serve `/admin/api/*` at `/admin/api/*` (no rewrite)
3. Serve `/{everything else}` from `index.html`

How can I do this in the root .htaccess?

So far, I've got:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But this doesn't handle the rewriting of `/admin/admin` to `/admin`. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin/admin [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|admin)
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is assuming there is no .htaccess inside `/admin/` folder. In case there is then use this rule there:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteRule ^/?$ admin [L]
```